# How can I enumerate all the files under \GLOBAL??\

Tags: winapi, device-driver

I have a bunch of device files which are accessible by using `\\.\name_of_file` as an argument to `CreateFile`.

I can use [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) to see the list of these files, but what I'd like to do is iterate over them programmatically.  Much Googling seems to be implying that I can use the Object Manager or the NT namespace, but I can't find an API for either of these, nor the source for WinObj to trawl through...

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: I dont know, if you exactly mean this, but function NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject / ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject is used to enumerate to all symbolic links.

Comment: You can browse some namespaces with the `for` command. Try this at the command line `for %i in (\\.\Mailslot\*) do @echo %i`

Comment: @ixe013: the 'for' approach doesn't seem to work for my files :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs to do this are documented **but are not guaranteed to work in future versions of Windows**.  With that in mind, look at the following:  [NtOpenDirectoryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470234%28v=vs.85%29) , [NtQueryDirectoryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470238%28v=vs.85%29)

Answer (score 3):

[Meandering Through the Object Manager](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=381) might be what you are looking for. [Osronline](http://www.osronline.com/) is just cool.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the pages I'd found in my initial trawl, but it doesn't cover any of the API calls I'd need to create a tool such as WinObj